# WCF, svcutil build proxy with /reference

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have a ClassLib call Id.API. Id.Web references this.

Within Id.API I have an Entity, MyEntity.

When I try to create the call to method SendEcho(MyEntity myentity), Id.Web project complains that it expects a param of

```
id.web.types.MyEntity
```

instead of

```
Id.API.MyEntity
```

Researching suggests to me that this is fixed using a reference switch on the svcutil command line.

Here is my example command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\SvcUtil.exe" 
http://id.web/Services/EchoService.svc?wsdl 
/config:C:\Projects\Id.Web\Interface\Services\EchoService.svc.config 
/reference:../bin/Id.API.dll
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot load reference assembly '../bin/Id.API.dll'

Cannot load file ../bin/Id.API.dll as an Assembly. Check the FusionLogs for more Information.

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Projects\Id.Web\Interface\bin\Id.API.dll' or one of its dependencies.
This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

How can i fix this? thanks

Comment: Oh - and did you look at the fusion logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What .NET framework version is Id.API.dll, and what .NET framework is the assembly that references it?  It sounds like the Id.API.dll is built with a newer framework than the project you're trying to reference it with.

Comment: Your comment lead me to discover that the version of svcutil may not have been the latest. Using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\SvcUtil.exe` fixed the problem.

Comment: Good deal - I'm glad I was able to help (albeit indirectly)

Answer (score 1):

I changed SvcUtil.exe path

from 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools
to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools

the error is disappear.